# Удалить сообщение бота

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Как удалить сообщение от бота?

```
 await bot.DeleteMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, message.MessageId);
```

Указанный код удаляет сообщения пользователя, а я хочу удалить поле с кнопками после нажатия на одну из них.

Comment: Ну так передавайте вместо `message.MessageId` нужное id сообщения бота. При отправки ботом сообщения, вам небось возвращается все его данные, включая id, вот сохраните это, а потом удаляйте, даже уверен, что есть нечто на подобии `message.Delete()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `message.Delete()` такого точно нет))), для этого как раз `bot.DeleteMessageAsync`, а `Message` это просто набор свойств